# Focus on first input on form load in polymer 2.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

In polymer 2.0, can you please guide how to focus on first input element on screen load in below code

```
<iron-form id="form1">
    <form>
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[showInput]]">
          <div id="firstInput">
                <paper-input class="input-width-250 align-right" id="account" label="Account" value="{{account}}" required></paper-input>
                <paper-input class="input-width-250 align-right" id="city" label="City" value="{{city}}" required></paper-input>
          </div>
      </template>
    </form>
</iron-form>
```

For this, I have tried below code in *constructor*, but getting '*Cannot read property '$' of null*' error.

```
document.getElementById('account').$.input.focus();
```

Comment: The problem solved by using **this.$.form1.getElementsByTagName("paper-input")[0].focus();** Also I removed template tag and used CSS property **(this.updateStyles)** to display/hide form1 block.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'autofocus' to the element you need. See exemple below.

```
    <paper-input autofocus class="input-width-250 align-right" id="account" label="Account" value="{{account}}" required></paper-input>
```